# how do I add an account into the built-in courier administrator group?

Tags: email-server, groups, courier

In the documentation it says that there is a built in administrators group, but how do i add an account to that administrator group

http://www.courier-mta.org/authlib/README_authlib.html

```
The access group name “administrators” is a reserved group. All
accounts in the |administrators| group automatically receive all
rights to all accessible folders.
```

Comment: Considered reading the documentation? I can not imagine that something as fundamental as adding a user to a group is not in there.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm being too simple, but isn't the answer directly above the very text you quoted from the documentation?

**group=name**

> This option is used by Courier-IMAP in calculating access control lists. This option places the account as a member of access group
>   *name*